# UWP MediaTranscoder throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, uwp, media

I want to convert a `.avi` video file to a `.mp3` audio file and used the following code:

```
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var video = await folder.GetFileAsync("video.avi");
var targetFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("audio.mp3");
var profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto);
var transcoder = new MediaTranscoder();
var prepareTask = transcoder.PrepareFileTranscodeAsync(video, targetFile, profile);
```

However `transcoder.PrepareFileTranscodeAsync(video, targetFile, profile);`throws a `NullReferenceException` despite neither `transcoder`, `video`, `targetFile` or `profile` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind found the issue `AudioEncodingQuality.Auto` is not working when the target file is empty. Using `AudioEncodingQuality.High` or something else works fine.